# Pass a varible as input to Date.UTC

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to use a Dynamic `Date` based on user input.
I am using `Date.UTC` for `HighCharts`, but it doesn't seem to work with variables.

This works :

```
chart1.series[0].update({pointStart: Date.UTC(2015,05,25)});
```

This doesn't work :

```
var myDate = "2015,05,25";
chart1.series[0].update({pointStart: Date.UTC(myDate)});
```

How do I make this work ?

Comment: `console.log` your myDate and see what format you are getting!! What I feel here is your update `function` is expecting `parameter` which may be of type `Date`! Just try converting it into `new Date(Date.UTC)`. Check **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp)** for more details!!

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to split your string, this should work fine:

```
var myDate = "2015,05,25".split(',');
chart1.series[0].update({pointStart: Date.UTC(myDate[0],myDate[1],myDate[2])});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fpa6yc4d/

Answer (score 1):

The first one which takes 3 parameters year, month, day. but the second one is only one parameter which is string. Try 3 different parameters for year, month & day

Answer (score 0):

After searching through the internet, I tried the following code, and it works.

```
startDate = "2015-05-25";
var d = new Date(startDate);
chart1.series[i].update({pointStart: Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate())});
```

Thanks for your support !